# Can't start apache2?

Tags: 10.04, server, apache2

I have installed apache2. But there is a problem with starting apache2 after update.

> apache2: Syntax error on line 215 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Cannot load /System/Library/Apache/Modules/mod_include.so into server: /System/Library/Apache/Modules/mod_include.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: How can I repair these files and directorys? My distro is 10.04 LTS

Comment: How did you install/update apache ? That line on your apache2.conf was not added by the default package apache installation.

Comment: Please update your question to add the contents of line 215 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: That looks like a configuration file from MacOS. Are you sure you've installed Ubuntu's apache2?

Comment: sasa, you should answer Joao Pinto's question. How exactly did you install apache? The supported way is 'sudo apt-get install apache2'

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Lekensteyn.  The module in question should be at `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_include.so`.  You need to replace this (and any other modules with invalid paths) pathname on the `LoadModule` line for include_module.

But without seeing at least some of the httpd.conf file, it's almost impossible to handle the syntax error.

Comment: There is nothing under /usr/lib/ no directory apache2. Reinstall apache2 but same..no apache2 directory. Not a MAC. Just HP laptop

Comment: I guess that mod_include.so is in package apache2.2-bin (at least in case of lucid), so it should be reinstalled, not apache2.